# Need help t convert string from c++ to c# format

Tags: c#, c++, string, format

we are in moving our code from c++ to c# and i need help with one of our formats.

int the c++ we have the floowing example (assume myString class has a Format function):

```
myString.Format("%02.0Lf", (long double)amount)
```

what is the quivalent format in c# ? is it :

```
myString = String::Format("{0:D2}", (long double)amount);
```

thanks all

Comment: why don't you simply test? in LinqPad say?

Answer (score 0):

c# has String class that contains a lot of functions for handling strings.

You could do what you want with String.Format(...)

```
myString = String.Format("{0:D2}", (long double)amount);
```

This page will help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

And here you can find the format strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
double amount = 12.3456;
string text = amount.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
String.Format("{0:D2}", amount)
```

If this is for an object/class. Consider overriding the class's `ToString()` method which is inherited for every class (part of the base `Object` class).